# How to add an `onclick` event for this button

Tags: javascript, function, button

I create button using js. How to add an `onclick` event for this this button.

```
var b1 = document.createElement("button");
b1.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default");
b1.setAttribute("id", "viewdetails");
b1.innerHTML = "View Details";
d3.appendChild(b1);
```

Comment: `b1.addEventListener("click", function(){})`; ??What is function in your terms?

Comment: For the button onclick?

Comment: ...or for generating such a button?

Comment: I want to write a function for button onclick

Comment: @AshishRanjan I'll check:)

Comment: @PoornaGamage: Okay, thanks.. it should work..

Comment: @AshishRanjan ,Scath ,Luca thumbs up! it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a function to the click listener, use `HTMLElement#addEventListener()`:

```
let b1 = document.createElement("button");
b1.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default");
b1.setAttribute("id", "viewdetails");
b1.innerHTML = "View Details";
b1.addEventListener("click", function() {/* your code here */});
d3.appendChild(b1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more way to do this: (Using Scath's Snippet)

**Use onclick attribte**

```js
var b1 = document.createElement("button");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d");
b1.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default");
b1.setAttribute("id", "viewdetails");
b1.setAttribute("onclick", "clickevent();")
b1.innerHTML = "View Details";
d3.appendChild(b1); 
   

function clickevent(){
console.log("clicked")
}
```

```css
.btn{

}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will call the function `func`.

```js
var b1 = document.createElement("button");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d");
b1.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default");
b1.setAttribute("id", "viewdetails");
b1.innerHTML = "View Details";
d3.appendChild(b1);  
b1.addEventListener("click", func)

function func(){
console.log("clicked")
}
```

```css
.btn{

}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `b1.addEventListener("click", function(){func()})` is unnecessary. `b1.addEventListener("click", func)` should work just as well.

Comment: You are both right thanks. I had b1.addEventListener("click", func()) and it was only calling it onload instead of click removing the parens made it work.